# Regress Market Cap on Price to Book ratio

Tags: regression, ratio

I am running a regression model of firms' market cap where the coefficient of interest halves when i introduce the PB ratio as a control variable (but is stable to numerous other robustness checks). Yet since the PB ratio contains Market Cap in its core, I am uncertain whether to include it at all in my model. Yet, the correlation coefficient between Market cap and PB ratio is 0.6. Should I include the PB as another regressor?

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, if you have $Y=\alpha+\beta X+\epsilon$ and $Y=A ; X=A/B$, clearly you have a problem of circularity: you cannot have the same information on the left-hand side and on the right-hand side. Remember that the $X$ variables are called *exogenous* variables. Here, clearly it is not.

May I suggest that you try to rewrite your formula such that the $A$ part does not appear on the left and the right ?

Comment: If I answered your question, please upvote my answer and select "accepted answer."

Comment: I don't seem to have earned sufficient reputation (15 points needed). Otherwise, I tried.